# Check if point is in multiple polygons MySQL

Tags: mysql, polygon, point

I have multiple polygons and I want to check if my coordinate is in one of them in MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Contains(
        GeomFromText('MultiPolygon(((0 0,0 100,100 100,100 0,0 0),(200 200,200 300,300 300,300 200,200 200)))'),
        POINT(150, 150))
```

For some reason this still selects everything from the table, even though the point 150, 150 is in neither of the polygons.

After this works correctly i could replace the 150, 150 with the actual lat and lng.

It also looks like it works when the point is not in either polygon.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  and add some data  as text , so that we can reproduce your problem

Comment: This query does not really make sense. Since the polygon and the point are constants, it will return all rows if the point belong to the polygon. Shouldn't the polygon be built from the data that's within each row of the table?

Comment: Yes but what im trying to show that in this example with what im trying to do none of the rows should be showing. Because 150, 150 is in neither of the polygons